# Can Signer Attachment pdfbytes be found in Docusign Connect webhook?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I have a Docusign Connect webhook which sends the documents in the envelope to an apps script listener, which converts the pdfbytes into PDF files and stores them on the Drive. Is it possible to also include the pdfbytes of signer attachment files (which seem to also be automatically converted to PDF)? I would prefer not to setup an API integration to extract this one additional file from the envelope.

I have enabled attachments in the Connect options, but it does not add what I was expecting.

Comment: Please see edit, I was wrong, added correction

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I was wrong, this is possible.

In the included data, select both documents and attachments. This will include the base64 of the attachments

Comment: Can you confirm where in the json data to find the base64 of 'Signer Attachments'? I can only find the base64 for the actual documents included in the envelope from the template itself.

Comment: Have you enabled both include Documents and Attachments?

Comment: The payload will contain an attachmentTabId within the documents object, which will store the PDF bytes of the signer attachments.